# Javascript Cookie not stored

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried to create a Javascript cookie in which I am creating and storing the cookie in browser and and checking if cookie is stored on Browser or not. If cookie is stored on browser it will return Welcome user Username otherwise it'll ask user to enter his name.

```js
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
    var user = getCookie("username");
    if (user != "") {
        alert("Welcome again " + user);
    } else {
        user = prompt("Please enter your name:", "");
        if (user != "" && user != null) {
            setCookie("username", user, 365);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<body onload= "checkCookie()">
<input type= "button" onclick= "checkCookie()" value= "val"/>
</body>
```

This code is prompting again and again to enter the cookie but not storing the cookie in browser 
Please have a look at this and find a way to solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: Code seems to work fine for me when I ran it locally.

Comment: Same, works as desired in IE11.

Comment: @user26837 What browser do you use

Comment: I am using Chrome 53

Comment: When I am running it locally, prompt keep coming again and again  instead of storing the cookie

Comment: Maybe you have cookies disabled in your browser?

Comment: No cookies are enabled in this browser. Other scripts are working fine

Comment: Were are you running it, are you just opening in file mode, or are you using a webserver?.

Comment: I am just running it as file mode

Comment: can you tell me if you are able to store other cookie values on other pages ? or is this problem specific to this code ?

Comment: Yeah on other pages cookies are stored properly